# Django 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'data'

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to do a post request to a API, and save the result into one of my database table.

This is my code.

**This is my model. patientId is a foreign key to the userId of MyUser table**

```
class MyUser(AbstractUser):
    userId = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=6, blank=True, null=True)
    nric = models.CharField(max_length=9, blank=True, null=True)
    birthday = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    birthTime = models.TimeField(blank=True, null=True)

class BookAppt(models.Model):
    clinicId = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    patientId = models.ForeignKey(MyUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    scheduleTime = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    ticketNo = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

**view.py . The api url is from another django project**

```
@csrf_exempt
def my_django_view(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        r = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/makeapp/', data=request.POST)
    else:
        r = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/makeapp/', data=request.GET)

    if r.status_code == 201 and request.method == 'POST':
        data = r.json()
        print(data)
        patient = request.data['patientId']
        patientId = MyUser.objects.get(id=patient)

        saveget_attrs = {
            "patientId": patientId,
            "clinicId": data["clinicId"],
            "scheduleTime": data["created"],
            "ticketNo": data["ticketNo"],
            "status": data["status"],
        }
        saving = BookAppt.objects.create(**saveget_attrs)

        return HttpResponse(r.text)
    elif r.status_code == 200:  # GET response
        return HttpResponse(r.json())
    else:
        return HttpResponse(r.text)
```

the result in the `print(data)` is this.

`[31/Jan/2018 10:21:42] "POST /api/makeapp/ HTTP/1.1" 201 139
{'id': 22, 'patientId': 4, 'clinicId': '1', 'date': '2018-07-10', 'time': '08:00 AM', 'created': '2018-01-31 01:21:42', 'ticketNo': 1, 'status': 'Booked'}`

But the error is here

`File "C:\Django project\AppImmuneMe2\customuser\views.py", line 31, in my_django_view
    patient = request.data['patientId']
AttributeError: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'data'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well if you are printing the `data` and you can see the `patientId` inside it, why are you trying to use `request` for that?

it can be done like this

```
    data = r.json()
    print(data)
    patient = data['patientId']
    patientId = MyUser.objects.get(id=patient)
```

Comment: sorry, just to clarify something. If my user model id has been rename to userId, will it become `patientId = MyUser.objects.get(userId=patient)` ?

Comment: yes, as you need to match with the column name in the query

Comment: This works nicely now. Thanks. I always thought request is usually the stapler for everything.

Answer (score 22):

Django rest framework has own Request object. You need to use [api_view](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/2-requests-and-responses/#wrapping-api-views) decorator to enable this request type inside function view.

Comment: As i am creating a view to call an api from another project, i don't think api_view works... or am i doing something extra here ?

Comment: @JinNiiSama api_view is exacly for such kind of situations. I just want to clarify that.request.data will only work with rest framworks Request, not with standard django HttpRequest. Snd to enable first one you need to use rest frameworks api view decorator.

Comment: Its this one, http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/#api_view,  correct ?

Comment: @JinNiiSama yes.

Answer (score 2):

Change this line

```
patient = request.data['patientId']
```

for this line:

```
patient = request.POST['patientId']
```

Answer (score 0):

Django rest framework has own `Request` object, You need to use the `api_view` decorator to enable this request type inside function view,
Just write before function `@api(['GET' as an example])`